# Ionic 2 ion-tab shows white screen if clicked twice

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ionic2

Hi I am building an app with Ionic 2 which has a Google Map implementation. Everything works fine with the app except if I am on the map tab and I hit the map tab again the map disappears. Has anyone ran across this issue or know of a fix to stop the map from disappearing?

Below is how I am calling the map

```
<div #map id="map" ></div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occur because of a ionic2 bug on tab. When you click twice same tab, the tab reload.

Fortunately, it was fix in the last version.
https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

You have to upgrade your ionic2 version to 3.1.1.